# Google+ Share specific article

Tags: anchor, share, google-plus

I have included the Google+ share url in my website (not the +1). However, it shares the entire page and not the specific article I want to link to. My article title has an anchor id, but when I add it to the share's url, it doesn't pick it up...

`<a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://mywebsite.com/pagetitle.html#anchorid" title="Google+" target="_new"></a>`

The logo of the page and a short description shows up, but it won't link to the specific article.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Google+ share button currently works only for whole pages and not sections.
The only way, though not very user friendly, is to split each content into single pages.

Anyone - pls correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the share button rather than the share URL to be able to share links with anchors. Even URL encoding the anchors results in them being stripped from the URL that is shared with the link. When using the button, specify the href value to include the particular anchor that you need.

**Another approach if share link is a requirement**....

Would be to implement on your site an alternate method for the anchors. For example, use http://mysite.com/?article=myarticleid where myarticleid is the same as the anchor and check for that on page load (source).

```
function getParameter(param) {
            var val = document.URL;
            var url = val.substr(val.indexOf(param))  
            var n=url.replace(param+"=","");
            alert(n); 
}
var anchor;

function checkForAnchor(){
  anchor = getParameter("myarticle");

  // Do something with anchor, see code examples below.
}

window.onload = checkForAnchor;
```

Then add some JavaScript at the end of that checkForAnchor() function that will scroll the page on load to the correct location or just jump to the anchor.

In jQuery, you might animate that effect like ([source](/questions/6451193//questions/6451193/)):

```
jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery('#' + anchor).offset()}, 1000);
```

In standard JavaScript, you could simply change the location and append the anchor:

```
window.location = '#'+id;
```